# byte array with variable length to number

Tags: java, arrays, byte, data-conversion

I need to convert a number to byte array and then back to number.
The problem is that the byte array is of variable size, so I need to convert a number given his byte length, the methods that I came up with are those: (Java)

```
private static byte[] toArray(long value, int bytes) {
    byte[] res = new byte[bytes];

    final int max = bytes*8;
    for(int i = 1; i <= bytes; i++)
        res[i - 1] = (byte) (value >> (max - 8 * i));

    return res;
}

private static long toLong(byte[] value) {
    long res = 0;

    for (byte b : value)
        res = (res << 8) | (b & 0xff);

    return res;
}
```

Here I use a long because 8 is the max bytes we can use.
This method works perfectly with positive numbers but I can't seem to make the decoding work with negatives.

EDIT: to test this I've tried with processing the value Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1 (-2147483647) and 4 bytes

Comment: Dunno if your issue is solved now but... See if my Answer helps you with handling large negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *After accepting this as working solution, the Asker made some further
>   optimizations. 
> I have included their own* [**`linked code`**](http://pastebin.com/JKy8s5A6) *below for
>   reference :*

```
private static long toLong(byte[] value) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
    final byte val = (byte) (value[0] < 0 ? 0xFF : 0);

    for(int i = value.length; i < Long.BYTES; i++)
        buffer.put(val);

    buffer.put(value);
    return buffer.getLong(0);
}
```

---

OLDER ANSWER

**edit** : Based on comments (understanding Question better)

To make your `toLong` function handle both **negative** & **positive** numbers try this:

```
private static long toLong(byte[] value) 
{
    long res = 0;
    int tempInt = 0;
    String tempStr = ""; //holds temp string Hex values

    tempStr = bytesToHex(value);

    if (value[0] < 0 ) 
    { 
        tempInt = value.length;
        for (int i=tempInt; i<8; i++) { tempStr = ("FF" + tempStr); }

        res = Long.parseUnsignedLong(tempStr, 16); 
    }
    else { res = Long.parseLong(tempStr, 16); }

    return res;

}
```

Below is related `bytesToHex` function (re-factored to work out-of-box with any `byte[]` input...)

```
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes)
{ String tempStr = ""; tempStr = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes); return tempStr; }
```

Comment: This is not variable, I cannot say "put this number in 5 bytes" or "get my number from those 5 bytes"

Comment: You aren't supposed to put in just 5 bytes only. All languages / OS read as 1, 2, 4 or 8 bytes at once. If your number needs 5 bytes only then you're already in a situation where you actually must read as 8 bytes. Use [**bit-shifting**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/141873/2057709) to keep your 40 bits (5 bytes) at one side of Array and fill remaining 3 byte slots with zero bits.

Comment: I did already do something like it (see my question) but the problem is that I don't know how to deal with negative values

Comment: What is the problem exactly? I tried `myByteArray = toArray(-2147483647, 8);` and I got result `FFFFFFFF80000001` which is correct. The **toArray** is your own function and result is checked via my function **bytesToHex**.

Comment: I made my tests using my methods and yout bytesToHex: byte[] toArr = toArray(Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1, 4);
        System.out.println(bytesToHex(toArr));
        System.out.println(toLong(toArr));
Result: "80000001" and "2147483649", negativity lost :/

Comment: I get your point now... check the new edit. I've tested the output and it works fine. **Note** : when you do `someNum = toArray( amount, length)` if _length_ does not fit the required _amount_ then answer returned is always _1_. Maybe you could have some safety check (ie: a `While` loop) where if result is an unexpected "1" then keep trying again with a continual _length+1_ increment (until a not-1 result).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I wrote a slightly optimized version of it (the string operations aren't really fast) here's the new version using java's ByteBuffer http://pastebin.com/JKy8s5A6

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apache Common [Conversion.intToByteArray](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Conversion.html#intToByteArray-int-int-byte:A-int-int-) util method.

JavaDoc:

> Converts a int into an array of byte using the default (little endian, Lsb0) byte and bit ordering

Comment: Just tested it:

Comment: `long v = Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1;
        byte[] res = new byte[4];
        longToByteArray(v, 0, res, 0, 4);
        long out = byteArrayToLong(res, 0, 0L, 0, 4);
        System.out.println(out);` negativity lost

Comment: @SnowyCoder if this answer works then mark it as solution using `✓` icon.

Comment: @VC.One This answer doesn't work, as written in the second comment it loses the number negativity